# Iframe load external website in asp.net mvc

Tags: iframe, model-view-controller

I am now adding an iframe mark

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="{{frameSrc}}" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

in my asp.net mvc website and I will use it to load external www.baidu.com. 
But the result is :
[image]

I have searched the net and didn't get the answer. I think maybe the route problem in the mvc that caused this, do you have any idea?

Comment: Have solved this by using  $scope.frameSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://" + $scope.selectedMonitor.videoNVRAddress); in angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to change src like this :$scope.frameSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://" + $scope.selectedMonitor.videoNVRAddress); in angularjs

The reason is that in default the angularjs will prevent the direct load of the source website so that to keep safe. Using $sce plugin in angularjs can solve this.